# I am trying to update score of the player in sql lite database in android but its not happening

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

This is the update function in DBHelper class, which updates the score by 10 after each correct answer. My insert function is working fine, but when the update function triggers app is changing its activity and score is not getting update

```
public Boolean updateScore(String username,Integer score)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("username", username);
    contentValues.put("score", score);
    long result = db.update( "scores",contentValues, username + " = ?", new String[] 
{username});
    if (result==-1) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

This is my coding behind the check button. It checks if the word is correct then the score is increased by 10. Insert function is working fine.

```
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            player.start();

            if (answer.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(easy_level.this,"Enter you guess first", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (answer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(pet)){
                Toast.makeText(easy_level.this,"You are correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                answer.setText("");
                pet = pets[random.nextInt(pets.length)];
                question.setText(mixWords(pet));
                count.start();

                //insertingScore
                if(score_int == 0){
                    Boolean insert = DB.insertScore(name,10);
                    score_int +=10;
                    score.setText(String.valueOf(score_int));
                    if (insert==true)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(easy_level.this,"added 10",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(easy_level.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }else {
                        score_int +=10;
                        score.setText(String.valueOf(score_int));
                        Boolean update = DB.updateScore(name,score_int);

                        if (update==true)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(easy_level.this,"updated 
10",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(easy_level.this,"update 
fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }



            }else {
                Toast.makeText(easy_level.this,"You are wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `db.update()` you are referencing the value instead of the column name

```
 long result = db.update( "scores",contentValues, username + " = ?", new String[] 
{username});
```

should be

```
 long result = db.update( "scores",contentValues, "username = ?", new String[] 
{username});
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my issue